# How to pass (and return) LINQ IQueryable<T> to a Function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, iqueryable

I'd like the ability to pass (and return) an `IQueryable<T>` to a function for adding expression logic:

```
public void getShips()
{
    var shipyard =
        from ship in db.Ships
        select new { ship };

    var ballerShips = GetExpensiveShips(shipyard);     
}

public IQueryable<T> GetExpensiveShips<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    return query.Where(q => q.NetValue > 150000); // <== Error CS1061
}
```

Returns this error:

```
Error   CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'NetValue' and no
extension method 'NetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I've tried defining an Interface for `shipyard` and adding `where T : IShipyard` but that seems to cause more problems and leads to substantial boilerplate.

I would also like to avoid executing the SQL till after passing through my function.

Is this possible?

Comment: I wasn't able to accomplish what I needed without adding hundreds of lines of interface/class crap, so I just copy/pasted the mostly similar LINQ statements and called it a day.  Sucks that it's not DRY, but at least I'm not adding 300+ lines of boilerplate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove some unnecessary complexity.

Change the last line of your query to:

```
select ship;
```

And then change your method declaration to:

```
public IQueryable<Ship> GetExpensiveShips(IQueryable<Ship> query)
```

Your method is already written so that it will only work on `Ship` instances - it uses the Ship.NetValue property. So, you need to be explicit that that's the type it should take. There's no need for this method to be generic.

Comment: "There's no need for this method to be generic." gets you the vote here. Using constraints seems like a somewhat noisy approach.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm going to have to create an interface/class for ship?  Is there any way to avoid doing so?  My classes would have to support lots of nesting which will be messy.

Comment: @jiy No, you don't need to create a class or interface. You're working with the `Ship` class that *already exists.* If you look at `db.Ships`, it's of type `DbSet<Ship>`. That's the type you're passing in, and that's the type you wrote the method to expect. All that's left is to tell the compiler.

Comment: Whoops, I just realized that you're adding extra complexity by adding an anonymous type (without any reason to do so). Updated my answer.

Comment: @JoeWhite Thanks for the explanation.  Unfortunately as my example is greatly simplified it doesn't express the actual complexity.  The IQueryable `shipyard` will be a combination of several joins and thus won't conform to what EF already knows about.

Comment: Okay, let's see if I understand: you'll have many different queries, with many different anonymous types, but you want to pass all of them to the same `GetExpensiveShips` method? Will all of those anonymous types have a property called `ship` of type `Ship`? If so, then (a) your code example wouldn't work anyway - you'd need to do `q.ship.NetValue` instead of just `q.NetValue`; and (b) you could try `IQueryable<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 2):

You need something, that contains `NetValue` property. `T` is generic type without properties. So, adding an interface is right way:

```
interface IShip
{
    int NetValue {get;}
}

class Ship : IShip
{
    public int NetValue {get;set;}
}

public IQueryable<T> GetExpensiveShips<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    where T : IShip, class
{
    return query.Where(q => q.NetValue > 150000);
}
```

Comment: One question: Why T:class?

Comment: @AlKepp EF can not work with structures and interfaces. It needs class for materialization of objects

Comment: Thanks, Backs!  I may end up going this route, but would it be possible to accomplish this without adding the Interface/Class?  That will lead to hundreds of lines of boilerplate =(

Comment: @jiy: You can never call T.Anything if T is not interface/class with that method.

Comment: @jiy I don't know your situation, it's just one solution. Also, you can use `Ship` instead of `T`, or use base class for all objects, that has `NetValue`. It depends on your project